# Logging in to external website(s) with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to log in to an external website using curl. I want the user to enter the username and password on my index page, and then when the user clicks on the submit button, the loginform will post both the username and password to logincheck.php. There it checks if the username is registered in the database. If this is true, then it should forward the username and password to the external site and try logging in there. If not, you should see an echo saying "failed".

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

ob_start();
$host="XXXXXXX";
$username="XXXXXXX";
$password="XXXXXXX";
$db_name="XXXXXXX";
$tbl_name="XXXXXXX";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['loginid'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
$loginUrl1 = 'http://externalwebsite.com/';

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE login='$myusername'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error(); exit;
}

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


$cookieFile = "test/myCookiefile.txt";
if(!file_exists($cookieFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($cookieFile, "w");
    fwrite($fh, "");
    fclose($fh);
}

if($count==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;

$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'gebruikersnaam='.$myusername.'&wachtwoord='.$mypassword);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_exec($curl);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    header('Location: http://externalwebsite.com/');
    curl_close();
}
else {
    echo "failed";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Now, it redirects just fine to the external website, but it won't attempt to log in on that site, no matter what I try. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you got the hand on the other site wich site is it? Are you trying to make a phishing site? :)

Comment: Hilarious. If I wanted to make a phishing site I'd hire some programmers to do that. Investments and stuff.

Comment: Ok, but what kind of site are you trying to bypass login step? Some known sites add an hidden random value in the post, to avoid this kind of manipulation...

Comment: huh, is this bypassing the login? This is merely meant as an external login site, the password checking and stuff is still going to be done on the actual site itself. It's basically the owner of that site who asked me to make this, and I'm 100% sure there is no hidden value or anything.

Comment: So test the `$result` by dumping it... What do you get?